# Store session objects between redirects

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, socialauth

We are using `SocialAuth` for authentication with `Spring 3` and having issue with sessions between redirects.

When we do  `return "redirect:myURL";` in controller (after authentication) redirection happening properly but, very frequently redirect creating new `session` instance instead of using my current `session` which results in `NullPointerException` when I look for certain variables I have stored in `session`.

I have added few `System.out` statements to prove that new `session` is being created.

```
Session id is before authentication...E7557680F892C6776F36691E9DF93CF5
session ID after authentication and redirct....     726C2EE5C240BDE4D217CBFDB9C47A0F
```

How can I store current `session` in Spring application context before redirect and use it after redirect based on session ID? Is there any other way we can work around this in Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `RedirectAttributes` Interface in Spring, it' is built for the same purpose you  are trying to implement. This basically preserve values between redirects and hence will eliminate your need of putting attributes in session and then getting them.

Here's the link

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html

Comment: What is the scope of these RedirectAttributes? Is it session? If so, this may not work in my case.

Comment: If you look at the API, you will generally get two method `addFlashAttribute ` and `addAttribute `. `addFlashAttribute` stores the object flashmap which is internally stored in session, these varaibles get removed once the redirect is complete while the `addAttribute` create the request parameters from your attributes